# How do I delete or move 3D prefab clones of the same name and tag on collision?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to achieve is when my prefabs instantiate in my spawn area when they collide then one either moves from another or is destroyed and another spawn replaces it. I tried to use tags to get the other prefab touching. I tried getting the names' prefabs. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I did just drag my game object into the prefabs folder to get prefabs. Heres my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    int counter = 0;
    public int max;
    //public GameObject objects;
    public GameObject[] objects;
    public GameObject[] objectsPrefabs;

    public Vector3 size;
    public Vector3 center;
    int xRotation = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (counter < max) 
        {
            Spawn();
        }
    }

    //void Spawn() 
    //{
    //    Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x / 2, size.x / 2), Random.Range(-size.y / 2, size.y / 2), Random.Range(-size.z / 2, size.z / 2));

    //    Instantiate(objects, pos, Quaternion.Euler(0, xRotation, 0));
    //    xRotation += 45;
    //    counter++;
    //}

    void Spawn()
    {
        objects = new GameObject[objectsPrefabs.Length];

        Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x / 2, size.x / 2), Random.Range(-size.y / 2, size.y / 2), Random.Range(-size.z / 2, size.z / 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            objects[i] = Instantiate(objectsPrefabs[i], pos, Quaternion.Euler(0, xRotation, 0)) as GameObject;
        }
        xRotation += 45;
        counter++;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (collision.transform.CompareTag("spawnwall"))
            {
                //if (objects[i].gameObject)
                //{
                Destroy(objectsPrefabs[i]);
                counter--;
                Spawn();
                //}
            }
        }

    }



    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
        Gizmos.DrawCube(center, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs on collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html), you must refer to `collision.gameObject` in order to refer to the *other* object the collision is referring to. Right now you are comparing the `spawnwall` tag against the tag of the game object this component belongs to.

When posing the questions, it would also be nice to know the following:
1. The desired output
2. The current symptoms

I also have the following concerns:
1. Are you sure your class members are initialized with the correct data? It seems to me that they are all either starting with C# default values.
2. Do you want the objects inside the area to do what you described when they (a) touch each other or (b) when they touch the area boundaries.

The way your current code is written makes me thinks that you have a bunch of objects inside a rectangular area. Then, when the objects collide with the boundaries of the rectangular area, they should be destroyed.

Comment: Hello and thanks,
what I want is when the objects collide one is destroyed. They spawn in the rectangular areas I set up. I forgot to mention I used collision for tags. I could try again.

Comment: How are you initializing your `objectsPrefabs` variable? There seems to be no initialization. To me it seems you are also missing setting the prefab object you want from a `[SerializeField]` member. It also seems like you want all these objects to be different since you have a `objectsPrefabs`, which would be an array of prefabs, correct? If so, you might have to look into doing something like [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-editable-array-of-fixed-size-in-inspector.504318/)

Comment: 1. For the desired output, I would like it when my instantiated prefabs are touching then one would be destroyed and the other would stay. 2. The current problem is that they still stay touching each other. 3. I'm not sure about the class members. I'm not sure if I'm doing any of this right. I know my instantiation and random spawning work, but not properly. 4 Option (a)

Comment: 1. For instantiation, it is taken care of in the Spawn() function. 2. I do want all my prefabs to be different.

Comment: Hm...it sounds like you have quite a lot going on. If you want to do something when the objects collide, then you should add a component to your instantiated objects that handles the logic for when they collide. The way it is coded right now makes it so that the walls are the ones listening to the collision against the game objects, that's why your objects are still touching each other.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at some more intro unity scripting tutorials. I know they are boring, but the fundamentals you learn from them can help you with this specific cases.